# Continuous distribution and independence

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

Problem: In a room, there are 4 boys from high income families, 6 girls from high income families and 6 boys from low income families. How many girls from low income families also need to be present for the random variables "gender" and "family income" to be independent when a child is randomly selected?

Can someone solve this problem? I'm pretty sure we need E(XY)=E(X)E(Y), where X is random variable for "gender" and Y is random variable for "family income" but I do not know how to find those expected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{Boy, High income} =4\\
\text{girl, High income} = 6\\
\text{Boy, low income} = 6\\
\text{Girl, low income} = x$$

$$ P(\text{Male - M}) = \frac{10}{16+ x}\\
P(\text{High income - H}) = \frac{10}{16+ x}\\
P(\text{Male High income}- MH) =\frac{4}{16+x} $$

Independence means that
$P(M \text{and} H) = P(M) P(H) $
$$\frac{10}{16+x}\frac{10}{16+x} = \frac{4}{16+x} $$

you need to introduce $9$ girls of low income

Comment: Yes you are right!@AndréNicolas

Comment: thanks, so I don't need to use expected values

Comment: If you consider that $X = 1$ if the individual is male and $X  =0 $ if the individual is female and $Y = 1$ for high income and $Y=0$ for low income then we showed that $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$. So we used expected values.